# What's wrong? I can't seem to close this code out

Tags: c#

I cant figure out how to close this out properly, no matter where i add a bracket it breaks the code.
I appreciate the help, thanks :)

```
            int NewID = Convert.ToInt32(Adapter.InsertQuery()); // new relationship id
            if (!Session.GetHabbo().Relationships.ContainsKey(Them))
                Session.GetHabbo().Relationships.Add(Them, new Relationship(NewID, Them, 3)); // create the relationship

            Session.GetHabbo().GetMessenger().UpdateFriend(Them, Session, true);
        }

        else

          {
            Habbo Habbo = PlusEnvironment.GetHabboById(Them);
            if (Habbo != null)
            {
                MessengerBuddy Bud = null;
                if (Session.GetHabbo().GetMessenger().TryGetFriend(Them, out Bud))
                    Session.SendMessage(new FriendListUpdateComposer(Session, Bud));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

P.S I'm still new to this.

Comment: How could we help if you're not showing the entire code?It might be that you have extra braces, who knows.

Comment: Missing an opening Bracket after if clause

Comment: I tried wrapping it in code tags but new to this site dont know how

Comment: Added a opening bracket and it fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a simple fix, but if you format your code this sort of stuff usually sticks out. In Visual Studio you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (in succession) and it'll format your code to the default.

```
int NewID = Convert.ToInt32(Adapter.InsertQuery()); // new relationship id
if (!Session.GetHabbo().Relationships.ContainsKey(Them))
    Session.GetHabbo().Relationships.Add(Them, new Relationship(NewID, Them, 3)); // create the relationship

    Session.GetHabbo().GetMessenger().UpdateFriend(Them, Session, true);
}
else
{
    Habbo Habbo = PlusEnvironment.GetHabboById(Them);
    if (Habbo != null)
    {
        MessengerBuddy Bud = null;
        if (Session.GetHabbo().GetMessenger().TryGetFriend(Them, out Bud))
            Session.SendMessage(new FriendListUpdateComposer(Session, Bud));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alright. Now that that's done. You're, in general, missing your beginning brackets on your if-statements.

```
int NewID = Convert.ToInt32(Adapter.InsertQuery()); // new relationship id
if (!Session.GetHabbo().Relationships.ContainsKey(Them))
{ // Added here
    Session.GetHabbo().Relationships.Add(Them, new Relationship(NewID, Them, 3)); // create the relationship

    Session.GetHabbo().GetMessenger().UpdateFriend(Them, Session, true);
}
else
{
    Habbo Habbo = PlusEnvironment.GetHabboById(Them);
    if (Habbo != null)
    {
        MessengerBuddy Bud = null;
        if (Session.GetHabbo().GetMessenger().TryGetFriend(Them, out Bud))
        { // Added here.
            Session.SendMessage(new FriendListUpdateComposer(Session, Bud));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So if you add those two brackets noted by the `// Added here` comments, that should work.